# React JS controlled controller

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have made this component called `ConstrainString`, if I don't pass the `onChange` it works fine, but when I'm trying to control it from the parent (where I use it) it's gonna be really slow like a huge speed difference between having `onChange` and not having `onChange`

`ConstrainString.js`:

```js
export const ConstrainString = ({cname, disabled, label, value, onChange, placeHolder}) => {
    const [input, setInput] = useState(value === undefined || value === null ? '' : value);

    const handleChange = event => {
        setInput(event.target.value);
        onChange && onChange({cname, value: event.target.value})
    };

    return (
        <div className="input-group input-group-sm">
            <div className="input-group-text">{label}</div>
            <input disabled={disabled} value={input} dir={'auto'}
                   placeholder={placeHolder} onChange={handleChange} className={'form-control'}/>
        </div>
    );
};
export default ConstrainString;
```

`MyIndex.js` (the parent):

```js
const MyIndex = ()=>{
    const [theConstrain, setTheConstrain] = useState('');
    const handleChangeTheConstrain = e => {
        console.log(e);
        setTheConstrain(e.value);
    };
    return (
        <ConstrainString cname={'keyword'}
                label={'Keyword'} value={theConstrain}
                onChange={handleChangeTheConstrain}/>
    );
};
export default MyIndex;
```

It seems fine so far, even you can see it in this [snippet](https://codesandbox.io/s/dank-cdn-ivzgb).

But if MyIndex.js was a huge page with table and sidebar and everything, the `ConstrainString` get slower.

Don't get me wrong I split everything in separate components in MyIndex but still...

Ps. I'm using Material-Ui and this the page I use my component in:

[image]

**How Can I Fix This? :-(**

Comment: What are you considering a huge speed difference? Nothing here looks like it should be observably slow..

Comment: I even copied this exactly into a stack snippet and it runs fine.

Comment: I still don't see a performance issue even using your sandbox.. Can you be more specific?

Comment: @BrianThompson It seems, I have made this example https://codesandbox.io/s/dank-cdn-ivzgb and there is no real difference between two modes, I should look for issue somewhere else because in my project it works really slow!

Comment: @BrianThompson Thanks and sorry for the trouble.

Comment: @BrianThompson Found the problem, don't know how to fix it. :-(

Comment: There's no new information in the question to make it answerable though. If `MyIndex` contains more things, and only is slow with those extra things - then you'll need to determine what's slowing things down there. **Remember** - updating state in a component causes that component and *all* it's children to re-render, so if you have some expensive components you may need to account for that. I can't say how since the best way will vary depending on the specific situation.

Comment: @BrianThompson Thanks, I'm trying to do as you say :-)